# MySQL : Problem in Updating a column for condition

Tags: mysql

I have one phone field column which contains phone numbers like that

```
'123456789'

'123-456-789'
```

etc

means it contain 9 digit number or number + hyphen.

I want to make a SQL query which updates all  records in `'xxx-xxx-xxx'` format.
I have made few attempts but cannot get exact solution.

Please any one help me.
Thanks in advance.....

Comment: So some of your records already have the hyphens, and some do not?  If so, when hyphens exist, are they known to be in the correct format?  Or could you have a situation like 123-456789?

Comment: I'd recommend removing the hyphens. You can add them at point-of-display, but there's no need to store them and doing so just adds the possibility of these format inconsistencies. I'd suggest making the phone number field an integer type.

Answer (score 2):

use something like

```
UPDATE mytable SET phone =  
CONCAT(SUBSTRING(phone, 1, 3),'-',SUBSTRING(phone, 4, 3),'-',SUBSTRING(phone, 7, 3))
```

Also to only get the rows that are missing hyphens you would say `WHERE phone not like '%-%'`

Comment: Some records contain 123-456-789 it would be update like 123--456--789.

Answer (score 0):

Close. You'd first need to test if the string contained a '-' before adding more, but that's the right track.

UPDATE mytable
SET phone = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(phone, 1, 3),'-',SUBSTRING(phone, 4, 3),'-',SUBSTRING(phone, 7, 4))
where INSTR( phone, '-' ) = 0;